# Why is Assigning a Object to a Map producing an empty object?

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading

I have the following `Store` class:

```
class Store
{
    public:
        Store() : m_npc_id(0)
        {

        }

        Store(const int npc_id,
            vector<std::string> categories,
            vector<StoreItem> store_items) :
            m_npc_id(npc_id)
        {
            m_categories = categories;
            m_store_items = store_items;
        }

        Store& operator=(const Store& rhs)
        {
            return *this;
        }

        vector<std::string> GetCategories() const;
        vector<StoreItem> GetItems() const;
    private:
        const int m_npc_id;
        vector<std::string> m_categories;
        vector<StoreItem> m_store_items;
};
```

When I call the following code, the object gets stored properly in the `store` variable...

```
const Store& store = Store(npc_id, category.second, items[npc_id]);
```

However, as soon as I try to insert the `store` variable into the a map of all `Stores`, it doesn't work... The object that gets stored is empty, and takes on the default constructor values for `Store`.

```
for (auto &category : categories)
{
    // In this case, category.second is a string value
    // items[npc_id] is a StoreItem

    const int npc_id = category.first;

    const Store& store = Store(npc_id, category.second, items[npc_id]);
    stores[npc_id] = store;
}
```

Comment: Your assignment operator doesn't assign the object.

Comment: why is your `Store& operator=(const Store& rhs)` empty? If you put a breakpoint inside this method you will notice that it will be called from this line: `stores[npc_id] = store;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your copy assignment operator is *completely wrong*.

```
stores[npc_id] = store;
```

If `npc_id` is not found in the map, the map first creates a new `Store` using the default constructor.  Then it attempts to copy assign from `store`.  And it copies using this code:

```
{
    return *this;
}
```

Given the fact you have a `const` member, it appears to be your intent to disallow copies.  In which case, the code is even more wrong.  To disallow copies, use `Store& operator=(const Store& rhs) = delete;`.

And you'll note that `stores[npc_id] = store;` no longer compiles.  Instead, you'll have to do something to avoid the copy.

```
stores.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(npc_id),
          std::forward_as_tuple(npc_id, category.second, items[npc_id]));
```

Don't like this code?  Make `Store` copiable instead:

```
class Store
{
    public:
        Store() : m_npc_id(0) {}

        Store(const int npc_id,
            vector<std::string> categories,
            vector<StoreItem> store_items) 
        :
            m_npc_id(npc_id), 
            m_categories(std::move(categories)), 
            m_store_items(std::move(store_items)), 
        {}

        const vector<std::string>& GetCategories() const;
        const vector<StoreItem>& GetItems() const;
    private:
        int m_npc_id;
        vector<std::string> m_categories;
        vector<StoreItem> m_store_items;
};

stores[npc_id] = store; //now this works!
```